# Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController:

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uicollectionview

Using tableview and trying to open **collectionviewcontroller which has storyboard and root view controller of the navigation controller**, when tableview cell is pressed. But getting error message that

Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case PDF: 
        viewController = [[[PDFExampleViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

        break;
    case IMAGE: 
//Rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller have no identifier. showDetail is the segue of the rootviewcontroller.

 viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showDetail"];
        break;
    case PROCEDURAL:
        viewController = [[[ProceduralExampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        break;
    default: 
        viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
} 


[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct storyboard identifier for you view controller? Case is important.

Comment: yes. when i add this [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self]; instead of that line then it gives message that Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ExamplesViewController: 0x7ab26a0>) has no segue with identifier 'showDetail'' which means tableviewcontroller should have segue with the collectionview to display when tableviewcell is pressed

Comment: Now looks like application did not entering non of cases. check with NSLog they're working